# Keras: cannot access training images inside on_batch_end callback

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I am training a CNN using Keras with TensorFlow backend, using imgaug for image augmentation.

I am also using Tensorboard to visualize training progress and results.

Since imgaug is applying (random) transformations to the input images, I would like to send (some of) the augmented images over to Tensorboard, so that I can visualize them and verify that everything is correct (eg: to check if I am applying too large translations, or blurring the images too much).

For this I created a custom Keras callback and am trying to input my logic in the on_batch_end method. I can send images to tensorboard alright, but can't find where I can access the augmented input images. Any tips on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to do that outside training by simply getting images from your generator.

If it's a regular `generator`:

```
for i in range(numberOfBatches):
    x,y = next(generator)
    #plot, print, etc. with the batches
```

If it's a `keras.utils.Sequence`:

```
for i in range(len(generator)):
    x,y = generator[i]
    #plot, print, etc. with the batches
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Indeed, I ended up doing that just to verify that augmentations are correct.

However, I would really like to be able the actual data that was used for training, since that could help debug more subtle problems

Comment: I don't think Keras offers this option, unless you change its source code ... There is probably some point where the method `fit_generator` will call `train_on_batch` with a batch taken from the generator. At this point you can try to write your own things.

Comment: thank, I ended up altering the generator itself to add fields to the model containing  the images and all the data I needed. The model is fed by keras into the training callbacks so that fixed int

Comment: @4sfaloth Could you please, post the code to see how you managed this?